Find $U$, such that $(G+U | -G-2U)$is Clifford
Given a square matrix:
$
\begin{equation}
G=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\left(\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
$
We can compose a block matrix $X_0=(G|-G)$, which will yield:
$
X_0=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\left(\begin{array}{cccc:cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right)
$
Note that both $G$ and $X_0$ are not Clifford Matrices.
Problem: Find an arbitrary non-zero square matrix U (same size as G), such that $(G+U|-G-2U)$ is a Clifford Matrix. Alternatively, prove that there exists no such $U$.
I don't know how to approach this problem.

What is a Clifford matrix?

@HerrWarum I used it as a short form for "Matrix representation of a Clifford operator". Alternatively, in my field (ZX-Calculus), it would be "matrix interpretation of a diagram that is part of the Clifford-Fragment"
